# How to clear results on googleBar gmap with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using googleBar on my gmap application, after i manipulate the results of the search i want to clear the results of the search, but without using the clear results button.
i want to clear the results with from my JavaScript function.

how can i do that?